# I can not access second view element by document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net

There is a view control on the page in a MultiView. I can access the textboxes in the first view with document.getElementById (id). What can be the problem if I can not access the TextBox in the second view

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate ids. Use classes instead.

Comment: Assuming you have multiple elements with the same id, selectors like `getElementById` will only return the first match. You either change it to not have duplicate identifiers, use data-attributes instead, i.e: `data-id="elementidentifier"` or use`getElementsBySelector`  - You could also use classes, though I rather use them only for styles so classes can be removed,added as needed when styles need to change, without impacting functionality. To get better help, please post your exact markup and script.